# Room error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Tags: android, kotlin, compiler-errors, android-room

I have this query to get a Stack from db, but when I try to compile, I have this error:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.Stack<kotlin.Pair<java.util.Date, java.lang.String>>>).
```

This is my query:

```
@Query("SELECT searchHistory FROM UserEntity WHERE id = :idUser")
abstract fun getSearchHistory(idUser: Int): LiveData<Stack<Pair<Date, String>>>
```

These are my converters:

```
@TypeConverter
fun toStack(value: String): Stack<Pair<Date,String>> = Gson().fromJson(value, object : TypeToken<Stack<Pair<Date, String>>>() {}.type)

@TypeConverter
fun fromStack(value: Stack<Pair<Date,String>>): String = Gson().toJson(value)
```

Somebody could help me resolving this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Can you include where have you used the `@TypeConverters` annotation?

Comment: @HenryTwist '@TypeConverters' are inside a class wich is called under '@Database'

Comment: Can you include it in your question? Note that I am referring to `@TypeConverters`, not `@TypeConverter`.